# How can I password protect the zip folder in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to password protect the zip folder not the files in zip folder using VBA.
for example: if there is folder test.zip and there is file test.xlsx in it. I want to have a password on folder test.zip. Can someone help? Will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: how are you zipping the files, where is the code that you use to do that?

Comment: Good VBA/Zip reference: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section7.htm

Answer (score 0):

This procedure accepts an argument named NewFolder, which represents the folder to which the user is trying to switch. If this folder’s name is Confidential, the procedure asks the user to enter the password. If the password doesn’t match, the Cancel argument is set to True, which means the folder isn’t displayed.

Hope this will help you:

```
Sub zip_activeworkbook()
  Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
  Dim FileNameZip, FileNameXls
  Dim oApp As Object
 
  If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  DefPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  If Len(DefPath) = 0 Then
    msgbox "Please Save activeworkbook before zipping" & Space(12), vbInformation, "zipping"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  
  If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    DefPath = DefPath & "\"
  End If
 
  'Create date/time string and the temporary xls and zip file name
  strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
  FileNameZip = DefPath & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) & strDate & ".zip"
  FileNameXls = DefPath & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) & strDate & ".xls"
 
  If Dir(FileNameZip) = "" And Dir(FileNameXls) = "" Then
 
    'Make copy of the activeworkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileNameXls
 
    'Create empty Zip File
    newzip (FileNameZip)
 
    'Copy the file in the compressed folder
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FileNameXls
 
    'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = 1
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    'Delete the temporary xls file
    Kill FileNameXls
 
    msgbox "completed zipped : " & vbNewLine & FileNameZip, vbInformation, "zipping"
  Else
    msgbox "FileNameZip or/and FileNameXls exist", vbInformation, "zipping"
 
  End If
End Sub
 
Private Sub newzip(sPath)
'Create empty Zip File
'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
  If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
  Open sPath For Output As #1
  Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
  Close #1
End Sub
```

You may find my version easier to use and understand. Here is the macro code along with an example of using it. The password is optional.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
    Lib "Shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
         ByVal lpOperation As String, _
         ByVal lpFile As String, _
         ByVal lpParameters As String, _
         ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
         ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long




Sub ZipFile(FileName As String, Optional ByVal Password As String)


    Dim CmdLine As String
    Dim Ext As Long
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim RetVal As Long
    Dim Path As Long
    Dim ZipName As String
    
      ' If no path is specified use the current directory
        Path = InStrRev(FileName, "\")
        FilePath = IIf(Path = 0, CurDir & "\", "")
    
      ' Check if file exists
        If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = "" Then
            MsgBox "File Not Found" & vbCrLf & "  " & FilePath & FileName
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
      ' Name for the zip archive
        Ext = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
        ZipName = FilePath & IIf(Ext = 0, FileName & ".zip", Left(FileName, Ext) & "zip")
    
      ' Command line string - file names must include quotes
        If Password = "" Then
            CmdLine = "-min -a -en " & Chr$(34) & ZipName & Chr$(34) & " " _
                    & Chr$(34) & FileName & Chr$(34)
        Else
            CmdLine = "-min -a -en -s" & Chr$(34) & Password & Chr$(34) _
                    & " " & Chr$(34) & ZipName & Chr$(34) & " " _
                    & Chr$(34) & FileName & Chr$(34)
        End If
            
      ' Command line String to Unzip a file
        'CmdLine = "-min -e " & Chr$(34) & ZipFileName & Chr$(34) & " " _
        '       & FolderPath
        
      ' Zip the file and save it in the archive
        RetVal = ShellExecute(0&, "", "WinZip32.exe", CmdLine, FilePath, 1&)
  
      ' Check for Errors are from 0 to 32
        If RetVal <= 32 Then
            Select Case RetVal
                Case 2     'SE_ERR_FNF
                    Msg = "File not found"
                Case 3      'SE_ERR_PNF
                    Msg = "Path not found"
                Case 5      'SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED
                    Msg = "Access denied"
                Case 8      'SE_ERR_OOM
                    Msg = "Out of memory"
                Case 32     'SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND
                    Msg = "DLL not found"
                Case 26     'SE_ERR_SHARE
                    Msg = "A sharing violation occurred"
                Case 27     'SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE
                    Msg = "Incomplete or invalid file association"
                Case 28     'SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT
                    Msg = "DDE Time out"
                Case 29     'SE_ERR_DDEFAIL
                    Msg = "DDE transaction failed"
                Case 30     'SE_ERR_DDEBUSY
                    Msg = "DDE busy"
                Case 31     'SE_ERR_NOASSOC
                    Msg = "Default Email not configured"
                Case 11     'ERROR_BAD_FORMAT
                     Msg = "Invalid EXE file or error in EXE image"
                Case Else
                    Msg = "Unknown error"
            End Select
            
            Msg = "File Not Zipped - " & Msg & vbCrLf & "Error " & RetVal
            MsgBox Msg, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        End If
```

Example of using the macro:

```
Sub ZipTest()

  ZipFile "C:\PF Credits.xls", Password:="123"
  
End Sub
```